# What's the Difference Between αχρι and μεχρι?

Tags: vocabulary, ancient-greek, greek-to-latin-translation

This is a question about ancient Greek language. I thought this would be the best place to post the question as there are other Greek questions here and stack-exchange doesn't have a Greek forum. If not, please feel free to direct the post elsewhere.

The words αχρι and μεχρι are both translated interchangably as "until, as far as, up to," etc. in every lexicon I've checked (Liddell-Scott Jones, the new Brill Dictionary of Ancient Greek, Septuagint lexicons, and BDAG are some of the key ones to name a few).

Then I found this website: https://www.abarim-publications.com/DictionaryG/a/a-ch-r-i.html

...which says the difference is μεχρι "expresses termination of time or place, without emphasizing the process of getting there (as αχρι, achri, does)." But the website doesn't cite any sources, acting as a source of its own.

1. Is that statement true? And is there a credible source that supports it?
2. Would someone please explain to me what is the real difference between these two words from a Classical (and if possible, also Koine) perspective, with some credible source reference(s) to back it up?
3. Do any ancient translations between Greek and Latin shed light on their difference of meaning?

Thank you and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to see any semantic differences between **μέχρι(ς)** and **ἄχρι(ς)** as prepositions and conjunctions. However we can detect a difference between them as adverbs: **ἄχρι** means completely; **μέχρι** means until a specific point and precedes a preposition or adverb. As examples of these meanings we can get

**ἀπὸ δ’ ὀστέον ἄχρις ἄραξε** Π 324

**μέχρι δεῦρο τοῦ λόγου** Πλ. Συμπ. 217Ε.

Therefore we can conclude that the website 's statement is doubtful.

Their etymology is also common: they both come from ***me-ghs-r-i** so that the second is the zero grade of the first.

Finally Latin may not help, because we translate the different meanings of **μέχρι** and **ἄχρι** by different latin words (usque, quousque, citra).

Comment: In μέχρι δεῦρο τοῦ λόγου I'd say μέχρι is a preposition rather than an adverb (*until* this point in the speech). Adverbial μέχρι seems to be rare, but LSJ does give an example ἐς γόνυ μέχρι χιτῶνα ζώννυσθαι.

Comment: Also, welcome to the site!

Comment: Thank you! I think that the adverbial interpretation of μέχρι in μέχρι δεῦρο is more convincing (an adverb determines an adverb); besides the fact that we have a complete meaning, we can also consider the primordial adverbial nature of prepositions, which survives even later. Finally, in my opinion it makes more sense the above approach than the (rare as well) determination of an adverb  (pure; not an adverb with article) by a preposition (like ἀπὸ τότε). I think the conversation is fruitful. Thanks again.

Comment: I think the issue is that adverbs don't generally govern other words, and μέχρι is clearly governing δεῦρο, just like in ἀπὸ τότε. If it were an adverb you'd expect it to be omissible.

Comment: "Prepositions define the relations of a substantival notion to the predicate. All prepositions seem to have been adverbs originally [...]" (Smyth, 1636). Hence ἀπὸ τότε is a great example of an adverb governing another adverb just like μέχρι δεῦρο or μέχρι(ς) ἐκεῖ or μέχρι(ς) ἐδῶ . Besides an adverb of place is a suitable choice for a semantic argument of μέχρι as an adverb.

Comment: But synchrony isn't diachrony, and the reason Greek prepositions are said to have once been adverbs, rather than to still be adverbs, is precisely the change in syntactic behavior by which they came to take complements. ἀπὸ isn't an adverb in ἀπὸ τότε, unless we call all Greek prepositions adverbs.

Comment: Of course I do not confirm anachronism. Preposositions as adverbs e.g. in a 400 B.C. text is a διασωθὲν ἐν χρόνῳ φαινόμενον. If you agree with Smyth 's definition (I agree), you cannot call ἀπὸ a preposition in ἀπὸ τότε; it is an adverb for Homer and it is a residue of its adverbial nature e.g. for Plato.

Comment: I'd say τότε and δεῦρο are acting substantivally in those phrases, or else that prepositions can take adverbs as complements. It seems arbitrary to me to say that the same word is an adverb if its complement is an adverb but otherwise a preposition; it's clearer to distinguish between prepositional uses and adverbial ones based on presence or absence of a complement. This is obviously a question of terminological preference, but I think the position I'm describing is conventional, see e.g. LSJ s.v. ἀπό which regards it as a preposition in all cases.

Comment: Anyway, whatever definitions one uses, in the context of this question the crux is whether μέχρι and ἄχρι have different meanings when used in the same syntactic environment, i.e. whether μέχρι δεῦρο means something different from ἄχρι δεῦρο. I don't think that's the case, but I could be wrong.

Comment: In Beekes' and Frisk 's Etymological you will find ἀπὸ as adverb and preposition.  As you understand, I cannot think that ἀπὸ here is not an adverb: βούλεται ἀντιάσας ἡμῖν ἀπὸ λοιγὸν ἀμῦναι (A 67).

Comment: Yes, I agree that in that example it's an adverb in tmesis (precisely because there is no complement).